# UWP Manipulation Delta

Tags: c#, canvas, textbox, windows-10-universal, image-manipulation

Is there a way to make it so that the element being manipulated with ManipulationDeltaHandler will only be manipulated when a user clicks or touches over that specific element?

I have the following code so far:

```
public void AddTextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();
        MyTextBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        MyTextBox.PlaceholderText = "Text";
        MyTextBox.Width = 250;
        MyTextBox.Height = 100;

        ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
        MyTextBox.RenderTransform = textBoxTransforms;

        AddHandler(ManipulationDeltaEvent, new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(TextBox_ManipulationDelta), true);

       parentCanvas.Children.Add(MyTextBox);
    }

    void TextBox_ManipulationDelta(object sender,
        ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        dragTextBox.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        dragTextBox.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

        resizeTextBox.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        resizeTextBox.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
    }
```

When touching/pinching anywhere on the canvas, the textbox will move/resize. I want it so that this only happens when the user touches directly within the bounds of the textbox. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't remember, but can't you call AddHandler on MyTextBox? Like so: MyTextBox.AddHandler(..);

Comment: I just tried this and for some reason this makes the textbox lose all dragging/resizing functionality...

Answer (score 1):

> When touching/pinching anywhere on the canvas, the textbox will move/resize.

If you didn't specify which `UIElment` to be set with `ManipulationMode`property  and [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_AddHandler_Windows_UI_Xaml_RoutedEvent_System_Object_System_Boolean_) method, they will take effects for the current whole page.

If you only want them take effects on the `TextBox`, you should specify them as follows:

```
MyTextBox.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;    
MyTextBox.AddHandler(ManipulationDeltaEvent, new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(TextBox_ManipulationDelta), true);
```

Pay attention that the `ManipulationMode` should be also be specified, otherwise the `Manipulation` for the `TextBox` will not work.